Can I "subclass" the browser's "Open in new tab"?
Working on a website with iframes.  Some links, if you choose "Open in new tab" will only open the iframe contents.
EDIT: if they right click and choose open a new window I want it to display in a new tab exactly the same thing that would be displayed if they just clicked on the link.
We'd like the user to be able to right click on any link and choose open in new window, and then display that Target in a new tab. Actual behavior is that it displays only part of the page in the new tab. My understanding is it's displaying the contents of the iframe page on the new tab.
I'm wondering if there is an easy way to "hijack" (on the desktop called "subclass") the Open In New Tab menu so that we can change the link, so that we supply our own link for that menu selection.

Yeah, nah, that’s going into the completely wrong and impossible direction. Try explaining your situation instead and ask for a solution to whatever it is you’re trying to solve.

You could detect if the page the link refers to is not opened in an iframe, and if it isn't you can reload the page in the correct parent page. This requires that you control the page the link refers to.

So you want "Open in new tab" to open something different from just clicking on the link? Why should the target of the link depend on whether you're opening it in the same tab or a new tab?

@barmar. I want the opposite, if they click open in new tab I wanted to navigate to the same thing it would if they just clicked on the link, but open that in a new tab. Currently only part of the new page is rendered in the new tab. I believe this is because the link was within an iframe.

@deceze I added and edit. Also see my reply to barmar.  Thanks!

Can you add HTML that demonstrates this problem? I don't think that's normally how it works. When you click normally on the link, the new page is opened inside the iframe in the same tab. When you use "open in new tab", the new page is opened as a top-level page in a new tab. I'm not sure what you mean by "only part of the new page is rendered in the new tab". What part of the page?

Do you want it to duplicate the top-level page in the new tab and replace the iframe with the target of the link?

There is no easy or difficult way to do what you describe. But there are ways to achieve the same effect. The simplest ways would be have every link in the iframe redirect through the parent page.
<a href=“/parentpage.html?iframe=/newChildPage.html” target=“top”>link</a>

You would then need a little bit of code either server or client side to update the iframe to the passed in child page.
Taking this one step further and you could add some JS to the link to intercept the click and have the iframe go direct to the new child page.
<a
  href=“/parentpage.html?iframe=/newChildPage.html”
  target=“top”
  onclick=“location.href=this.src.split(‘=‘)[1];return false”
>link</a>

Now when the link is click the iframe will go directly to the new page, and open in new tab will load it via the parent page.
